# What's the most efficient way to input integers into a 2D array?

Tags: java, arrays, integer, java.util.scanner

This is what the user interface should look like when executing:

```
Enter number of rows/columns:
3

1,0,1
1,1,0
0,1,1
```

So all the numbers are input by the user; creating the 3x3 array is straight forward, but I can't figure out a good way to put each line of the matrix the user entered into the array that wouldn't involve a lot of switch or if/else statements.

Comment: `Scanner::nextInt`?

Comment: Well, to start the most efficient way of doing this would be to save the input in a file or test harness, so you don't have to manually enter the data each time you want to run a test of your program.

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See also: [ask]

Answer (score 1):

Well, the total number of elements in a square matrix would be the number you have there, squared.

```
int totalElements = rowsCols * rowsCols;
```

And you can read all the elements in a loop with `Scanner`.  One way is to note that you can change a linear index to rows and columns with some math.

```
for( int i = 0; i < totalElements; i++ ) {
  int row = i / rowsCols;
  int col = i % rowsCols;
  matrix[row][col] = scanner.nextInt();
}
```

To use commas, you'll have to first set the scanner to use either white space or commas as delimiters.

```
scanner.useDelimiter( "[\\s,]+" );
```